# Java - ConcurrentLinkedQueue - poll all

Tags: java, collections

Assume I have the class field of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` type. Some methods of this class are offering the new elements to this queue. And some other methods need to poll for all the elements that are inside queue *at this exact moment*.

I can't use `poll()` in loop, because there is a chance that some elements might be offered to this queue while loop is still unfinished. And if the new elements are offered faster than I poll them, I think it can even be an endless loop. So I need some kind of `pollAll()`.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Maybe there is a collection suitable for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can change your application to use one of the `BlockingQueue` implementations, there is a method [`drainTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-) that seems to do exactly what you want. It removes the current contents of the queue and transfers them to a destination collection.

There are a variety of `BlockingQueue` implementations; they should all be thread-safe. Oddly, it's not specified that `drainTo` is atomic, though it is in the implementations I checked (`ArrayBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue`).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you need some sort of "pause" moment. One way of doing:

```
    AbstractQueue<Object> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    int size = queue.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Object object = queue.poll();
        if (object == null) {
            // Collection has shronk break
            break;
        }
        // Do processing here
    }
```

By storing size into a local variable, the size will not change and you can use that amount of elements to process. If during process elements are added it won't be affected with an endless loop.

**UPDATE**: The `.iterator()` is probably better to use than my first example:

> The returned iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will
>   **never throw ConcurrentModificationException**, and guarantees to
>   traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator,
>   and **may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications**
>   subsequent to construction.

**UPDATE 2**: This is the method that will take all the elements also the deleted once and process it.

```
        AbstractQueue<Object> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        queue.add("Test1");
        queue.add("Test2");
        queue.add("Test3");

        Object[] objList = queue.toArray();

        queue.remove("Test2");

        for (Object obj : objList) {
            // Make sure you delete it, because we don't use .poll
            // Put it at top, to reproduce the poll as much as possible
            queue.remove(obj);

            // Do processing
        }
```

This will output:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Because of the copy to the new `objList[]` it will also show "Test2". This example may cause issues with the `.remove()` method if duplicates are added into the list. Because if and element is added is duplicate to the object in `.remove()` then that object is instantly removed.

Also note that this approach is slower, because `.remove()` need to loop through elements to find it O(N1), where `.poll` is instant O(1).

Comment: It can be an option. But what if someone's deleting elements while I'm iterating the queue this way? It would be nice to have protection from this - read deleted elements like they are still there. Maybe there is a way to "copy" the queue in it's current condition? Unfortunately `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` doesn't implement `Cloneable`

Comment: @coolguy You have a valid point. I updated the question. In this case results of `poll` should be validated in case of shrinking collections. As the document stated 'Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.' so with `null` you are sure the collection is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a chance of processing the wrong elements. Assume that there were 5 deletions and 10 additions to this queue, while the loop is running. I won't process these 5 deleted elements (but I'd like to) and I will process 5 elements that were added after I started the loop (and I don't want to process them).
If there won't be another options I'll do as you described, but I hope there is something more suitable

Comment: @coolguy I have updated the answer with another solution, however it has some side effects which is described.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that the OP does not want to use the `poll()` method, I would be surprised if async tasks were feeding records to the list faster than the poll() method can drain them.  If such were the case then a different high-throughput, clustered architecture would likely be necessary (Kinesis Firehose or similar).

I ran a test on a MacBookPro M1 with Java 11 and found the loop shown below could drain records at a rate 1.5 to 2.0 million per second.

I propose the following as a simple way to drain:

```
    public List<MyRecord> getRecords(){
        List<MyRecord> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!records.isEmpty())
            result.add(records.poll());
        return result;
    }
```